# Google map in fragment class not reloading in android

Tags: android, google-maps, fragment

in my application i'm loading map in navigation drawer fragment class.
first time when i'm opening map fragment its showing me map but on second time following fatal exception-

```
E/AndroidRuntime(5881): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f050025 (com.example.myapp:id/mapfragment) for fragment Fragment{41d89968 #1 id=0x7f050025}
```

xml code-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mapfragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</LinearLayout>
```

java code-

```
View v;
Fragment mf;
MapFragment m;
private GoogleMap map;
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
try {
            //Fragment videoFragment = new DealerLocations();
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);
        } catch (InflateException e) {
        }
Fragment mf = new Fragment();
        mf.getFragmentManager();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapfragment, mf).commit();

        m= (MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
        map = m.getMap();
}
```

I also wend through many links like- [When inflating fragment which was previously inflated app crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449124/when-inflating-fragment-which-was-previously-inflated-app-crashes?rq=1) , [Android, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id [..] for fragment [..]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935518/android-java-lang-illegalargumentexception-no-view-found-for-id-for-fragm) but not getting solution.
Is there any solution for this?

Comment: I have already added that part.see my question again.first time when i select option my activity for map its showing me map..but when second time giving exception

Comment: sorry that is not he mistake. Your error is here `fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapfragment, mf).commit()`;  Your log says `No view found for fragment` can't find  `id/mapfragment`.

Comment: whats the mistake then?what should i do??

Comment: Use intrface as a callback to the activity and from activity replace existing fragment with new one

Comment: you should use MapView if you want map in `fragment`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46581/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-yuva)

Comment: but i'm adding polyline on google map.thats why i'm using it.i can't use mapview

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try this:

```
m= (MapFragment) getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
map = m.getMap();

getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mapfragment, mf).commit();
```